# WCF & Class Library: Using Data Transfer Objects to Simplify Serialization resulting in "Hidden Base Properties"

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, inheritance

As most of us know, WCF does not support inheritance in the "object oriented" sense of the word.  That being said, there are workarounds, but they cost overhead.  Some of these workarounds include KnownTypes and ServiceKnownTypes.  In order to simplify the messaging process across the wire and maintain performance I am considering the use of "Data Transfer Objects".  I have tested these objects in an "Entity Class Library" and in a test library following two separate CLR inheritance structures.  Below is a simplified representation of each:

First Case:
[image: First Inheritance Case Diagram]

This case has the BookDTO inherit from the same IBook interface that the Book class inherits from.  There is no "Direct" inheritance from Book to BookDTO.

Second Case:
[image: Second Inheritance Case Diagram]

This second case allows BookDTO to inherit directly from Book and IBook.  This seems like the most flexible structure as it will support object oriented code to allow loose coupling and interchangeability between Book and BookDTO via direct casting if needed.  In addition, there is a logical parent with Book as there is with the IBook interface.  The obvious problem, however, is this case throws warnings in Visual Studio due to the fact that any implementation of WCF DataMemberAttribute attributes on the properties of the implicitly included interface members will hide the parent class properties.

My question: If my intention is to allow proper inheritance in the class library while supporting a simplified messaging infrastructure via "Data Transfer Objects" is it advisable to create local versions of properties that Get and Set the parent properties?  See code reference below:

```
[DataContract(Name="BookDTO")]
class BookDTO: Book, IBook
{
    [DataMember(Name="Author")]
    string Author { get { return base.Author; } set { base.Author = value; } }

    [DataMember(Name = "Publisher")]
    string Publisher { get { return base.Author; } set { base.Author = value; } }

    [DataMember(Name = "Id")]
    int Id { get { return base.Id; } set { base.Id = value; } }

    [DataMember(Name = "Name")]
    string Name { get { return base.Name; } set { base.Name = value; } }
}
```

It is true that this will throw compiler warning CS0108 (Level 2 warning).  I can overcome this by the use of the 'new' keyword.  My question is that given the logical inheritance of the object oriented code is the structure in case two above advisable?  The ability to flatten the class hierarchy for serialization has its benefits, but I will need to add the DataContractAttribute and DataMemberAttribute to each property.

The reason I am doing this is that there are several custom types that will carry array serialization in the actual production code for "Book" and "BookDTO".  Additionally, I am expecting more than one type of product, but the "Product" class will remain abstract and should never be implemented in and of itself.

Let me know if I am correct in my gut fealing with case two, or if I need to consider the "warning free" structure in case one where BookDTO only derives from the IBook interface.

Additional Note:  I like the structure in case two as it supports upcasting from BookDTO to Book ... (Book)BookDTO.  Upcasting is much less expensive (almost free) in the OOP model under ASP.NET than it would be to support a casting structure as follows:  (Book)(IBook)BookDTO  ... This would be more expensive if developers using this entity library decidted to take the sortcut and cast between objects.  Further, casting would require going back to the root interface.  This just makes me cringe a little ...

Comment: Your DTO should not be implementing the `IBook` interface. What if your DTO wants to have a different set of properties than the entity? And certainly, the DTO should have no behavior, yet the entity might want some behavior.

Comment: +1, Fair point.  however, the production environment will have products, but it will also have additional interfaces for how the concrete products are deployed.  Example: BookBLL, BookDAL for the domain layers will want to draw from Book.  IBook tends to hold only the properties.  IDomainObject would have the methods (e.g. CreateNew(), Update(), et cetera) that a "Book" or a "Magazine" could draw from.  The reason for this is that I cannot implement any method definitions in "Book" within my entity library that would require Data Access Layer logic as it would violate data source versatility.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Ahh... You just shed light on another issue I have been wrestling.  Custom types that do not serialize well and converting / parsing them before and after serialization.  Thus, they may benefit from seperation from the IBook interface directly.  So an asnwer could be: Use 'new' to hide, and drop the direct reference to IBook as it is already parent to Book.  Correct?

Comment: No. Make the classes independent. Do not derive BookDTO from Book.

Comment: If I do as you say I can see the value if Book methods change but the DTO does not need to (and vis versa).  This leads me to a new crossroads.  If there are 20 types of concrete objects derived from the abstract Product class, each has their own DTO, and I want to write decoupled code I would then need to either 1, write a service for each product type expecting it's DTO or 2, hard code dealing with any DTO comming in based on reflection (not liking this).  1 makes sense, but concerns me if product types bloat in the future.  In OOP I would just accept anything that derives from IProduct.

Comment: @JohnSaunders how would you address the above comment in the case the DTO is independent?  I was originally leaning toward an abstract factory model in the domain layer.  Would you recommend another strategy, e.g. dealing with the DTO's when they arrive in a hard coded fashion, or separating each type into its own service?  Answer to this will clarify your comment for me.  Thanks John.  As always, I respect your opinion.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm at work right now and don't have time for a discussion or chat. I don't understand why you think you'd have to write one service per type. I will suggest that the types that travel across the wire should not be "object-oriented" or "polymorphic". If you want the types used in your implementation to be OO, that's fine. But the DTOs should be about transferring data across the wire; the implementation and entity types can be whatever you need in order to implement your services.

Comment: @JohnSaunders +1 again.  I agree with your comment on non OOP / polymorphic types across the wire 100% (thus DTO). I will diagram this out and let you know if your comments provide the answer.  You have given me a good chunk to gnaw on.  May be too much time in front of code on my end.

Comment: @JohnSaunders I get it.  I found a GREAT article touching on this (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee236638.aspx). What I am really struggling with is the choice between use of DTO's and the fact I will have 60+ Entities.  This opens the concern that pure DTO + Adapter pattern may add excessive overhead for a one man project.  I needed to step away and take a fresh look at what I was doing.  The "hybrid" approach above may "work" but does require domain knowledge, which I can't expect end users of the library to have in good conscience.  Thanks for stearing me straight.

Comment: Consider using code generation, especially [Code Generation and T4 Text Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb126445.aspx)

Comment: @JohnSaunders Thanks for the advice.  After looking at it with new eyes it appeared like I was dealing more eith a "proxy" like design pattern than a true DTO / Adapter pattern.  In all good conscience I would need to defer to you to post the Answer as I would have taken far longer to come to this realization on my own.  The DTO's should anticipate the UI requirements, not simple object / list requirements.  The point of the DTO is to minimize round trips and consoliodate required data into one trip if possible.  I will look into the Code Generation link you sent.  Thus, seperate interface.